Sequelize and SQL Server
I am building a React app with Node.js and Sequelize with SQL Server. I am running into the below error. I am using the v7 alpha version of Sequelize.
My model is below:
import { Sequelize, DataTypes, Model } from '@sequelize/core';
import { Attribute, PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, NotNull, Table } from '@sequelize/core/decorators-legacy';
import { MsSqlDialect } from '@sequelize/mssql';
import { genSalt, hash } from "bcrypt"

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  dialect: MsSqlDialect,
  server: process.env.SERVER,
  port: process.env.PORT,
  database: process.env.DB,
  authentication: {
      type: "ntlm",
      options: {
          domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
          userName: process.env.USER,
          password: process.env.PASSWORD,
        },
  },
  trustServerCertificate:true
});

export class User extends Model {}

User.init(  {
  pk_user:  {
    type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
    allowNull:false,
    autoIncrement:true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  email:  {
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    index: {unique:true},
    //NotNull:true,
    allowNull:false
  },
  password:  {
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
    //index: {unique:true},
    //`NotNull:true,
    allowNull:false
  },
  first_name:  {
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  last_name:  {
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  image:  {
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  color:  {
    type:DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  profile_setup:  {
    type:DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    NotNull: true,
    defaultValue: false
  },
  createdAt:  {
    type:DataTypes.DATE,
    //NotNull: true,
    //defaultValue: false
  },
  updatedAt:  {
    type:DataTypes.DATE,
    //NotNull: true,
    //defaultValue: false
  }
}, {
  sequelize,
})

User.hooks.addListener('beforeSave', async function(User)  {
    const salt = await genSalt();
    User.password = await hash(User.password, salt);
  
})

export default User;

I created the table manually in SQL Server.
With the above model, I am able to insert into my table and perform findAll, but I am unable to findAll/findOne with a where clause. I can't even findByPk.
I get this error:
{
  err: BaseError [SequelizeBaseError]: Invalid value received for the "where" option. Refer to the sequelize documentation to learn which values the "where" option accepts.
  Value: { email: 'Science' }
      at WhereSqlBuilder.formatWhereOptions (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\where-sql-builder.js:164:13)
      at MsSqlQueryGenerator.whereItemsQuery (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\query-generator-typescript.js:554:33)
      at MsSqlQueryGenerator.selectQuery (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\query-generator.js:973:28)
      at MsSqlQueryInterface.select (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\query-interface.js:500:37)
      at User.findAll (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\model.js:1047:47)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:105:5)
      at async User.findOne (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\model.js:1195:12)
      at async login (file:///C:/web/EvolveChat/server/controllers/authController.js:55:22) {
    [cause]: TypeError: Expected type to be a string, a DataType class, or a DataType instance, but got STRING {
      usageContext: undefined,
      options: { length: undefined, binary: false }
    }.
        at normalizeDataType (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\data-types-utils.js:62:11)
        at Sequelize.normalizeDataType (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\sequelize-typescript.js:843:58)
        at Sequelize.validateValue (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\sequelize-typescript.js:836:17)
        at MsSqlQueryGenerator.escape (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\query-generator-typescript.js:654:20)
        at WhereSqlBuilder.formatBinaryOperation (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\where-sql-builder.js:528:105)
        at C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\where-sql-builder.js:288:21
        at #handleRecursiveNotOrAndNestedPathRecursive (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\where-sql-builder.js:566:14)
        at WhereSqlBuilder.formatPojoWhere (C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\where-sql-builder.js:249:60)
        at C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\where-sql-builder.js:160:23
        at C:\web\EvolveChat\server\node_modules\@sequelize\mssql\node_modules\@sequelize\core\lib\abstract-dialect\where-sql-builder.js:230:16
  }
}

My table schema (manually created) is shown in the screenshot here. I've been stuck on this for hours and can't get the where clause to work. Raw SQL works, but I would like to have the option to use the CRUD helpers if possible
I tried different string combinations, tried different find functions from Sequelize and even tried downgrading to the stable version of Sequelize. I was expecting to be able to use the where clauses in the find functions.
Edit 1
I am adding my function call below:


export const login = async (request, response, next) =>    {    
    try{
        //await User.sequelize.sync();
        const {email,password} = request.body;
        if(!email || !password) {
            return response.status(400).send("Email and Password is required.")
        }
     
        const user = await User.findOne({
            where: {
              email: 'Science',
            },
            order: [[ 'pk_user', 'DESC' ]],
        });
        if (!user)  {
            return response.status(404).send("User with the given email not found.")
        }
        console.log({user});
        const auth = await compare(password, user.password);
        if (!auth)  {
            return response.status(400).send("Incorrect or invalid password.") 
        }
        response.cookie("jwt", createToken(email,user.pk_user, {
            maxAge,
            secure:true,
            sameSite:"None"
        }));
        return response.status(200).json({user:{
            pk_user:user.pk_user,
            email:user.email,
            first_name:user.first_name,
            last_name: user.last_name,
            image:user.image,
            color:user.color,
            profile_setup:user.profile_setup
        }})
    } catch(err)    {
        console.log({err});
        return response.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
    }
}



Edit 2
I got this issue resolved. Apparently I had installed sequelize/core and sequelize/mssql. I uninstalled all Sequelize dependencies and installed sequelize/mssql only and that got the find functions working with where clauses.

Please also include the function call, the issue seems to be in what are you sending to it.

I have edited my question to include the function call. Thank you.

Hmm, may I ask you also to set  logging: console.log, in Sequelize config to see what how it actually interprets the 'Science' value. Seems like the model definition is messed up, but not sure by what exactly

I added it but the error is exactly the same. The only thing that was added was:
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Which I'm assuming is part of the authenticate method
I did try to extend the model using the decorators as described in the sequelize docs, but it kept throwing an unexpected token error for the "@" symbol so there might be something wrong with the packages themselves.

Why are you using an alpha version? Do you need anything specific about this alpha version? If the answer is no you should stick with the stable one.
