Sequelize sync SQL Server database
I have a question regarding the sync method in Sequelize with SQL Server. To summarize the problem: I have a model with a unique column, and when the table doesn't exist or the database is empty, the sync with the alter option set to true works fine and creates the table without any issues.
However, if the table already exists and I run sync with alter set to true, Sequelize attempts to alter the table with an incorrect query.
Below is my model, my sync, and the query that catches an error.
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "user",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique : true,
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    }
  );

  return User;
};

and here is the query that catches an error.
sql: 'ALTER TABLE [users] ALTER COLUMN [username] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL UNIQUE;',

and sync method
 await models.sequelize.sync({ alter: true, logging: console.log });

Where does the problem come from? Is Sequelize not compatible with SQL Server for alter: true, or is there an issue in my model?
Edit 1: Here is is my config file
module.exports = {
    database: {
        username: "sa",   
        dialect: "mssql",                     
        password: "mypassword",   
        database: "test",        
        host: "localhost",                     
        port: 1433,                            
        dialectOptions: {
            options: {
                encrypt: true,                 
                trustServerCertificate: true   
            }
        },
        logging: console.log,                 
        pool: {
            max: 5,                            
            min: 0,                          
            acquire: 30000,                   
            idle: 10000                        
        }
    }
}

And here Sequelize was declared
// Add logging: false to your config object
const sequelizeConfig = {
  ...config.database,
};
 
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  sequelizeConfig.database,
  sequelizeConfig.username,
  sequelizeConfig.password,
  sequelizeConfig
);
 
fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function (file) {
    return (
      file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
    );
  })
  .forEach(function (file) {
    const modelDefiner = require(path.join(__dirname, file));
    const model = modelDefiner(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });
 
Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});
 


how did you init your sequalize? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79122564/sequelize-and-sql-server for dialect etc

@siggemannen thank's for your reply, i edited my question and added the sequilizer init

Aside... is your username column really an integer?

@AlwaysLearning no it's a text, sorry about that copy/paste

can it be that the schema was initially created with username as an  Integer ?
Please verify that by running:
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'username';
Furthermore you might wanna try specifying the length of the string type:
type: Sequelize.STRING(255)
I remember sequelize having issues, depending on the used dialect

@JMB Thank you for your response, but the issue isn’t with the column type. Rather, the problem is that Sequelize is attempting to run a script that isn’t executable on SQL Server, as you can't alter a table to set a column as unique.

it seems to be using correct dialect, but i don't know, maybe what you want to do isn't possible for sequalize, or you're on older version. In general, a pure ALTER without first dropping unique constraint won't work at all. These orms are often too much trouble anyway
